# Why every set which is in $\mathcal{U}$ intersects with $S$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have a lemma in my textbook and I don't understand a thing in its proof.

Definition 1: A topological space $T$ is compact if every open cover of $T$ has a finite subcover.

Definition 2: A subset $S$ of $T$ is compact if every open cover of $S$ by subsets of $T$ has a finite subcover. This is the same as $S$ being compact with the subspace topology.

Lemma: If $T$ is a topological space and $S\subset T$ then $S$ is compact in the sense of definition 2 if and only if $(S,\mathcal{T}_S)$ is compact in the sense of definition 1.

The proof in the textbook is the following:

Suppose that $S$ is a compact subset of $T$ (using def 2). Any open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $(S,\mathcal{T}_S)$ consists of sets of the form $U=V(U)\cap S$ where $V(U)$ is open in $T$.

> Here I don't exactly get why every set is of the form $U=V(U)\cap S$. Why do they necessarily have to intersect $S$? The definition of an open cover of a set $A$ is: collection $\mathcal{U}$ of sets whose union contains $A$:
> $$A\subset \bigcup_{U\in \mathcal{U}}U$$
> Where $U$ are open sets.... So if $V(U)$ are open sets, and $\mathcal{U}$ is a union of these open sets, then it is enough for one of these sets to contain $S$ (and hence have any kind of intersection) for the collection $\mathcal{U}$ to be called a cover? So why do they show that every set which is in $\mathcal{U}$ intersects with $S$?

(The proof continues but this is the part which I didn't understand)

Comment: A set $W \subseteq S$ is open in the subspace topology if and only if $W=S \cap U$ for some open set $U$ in$T$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, that I know. But it says that $S$ is compact if every open cover of $S$ _by subsets of_ $T$ has a finite subcover. Doesn't this mean that in some of the open covers of $S$ there will be Sets which don't intersect $S$?

Comment: What is wrong if some of them are empty? That makes no difference to the proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy oh okay. I just wanted to clarify that some of them may be empty. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Recall the empty set is open!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **definition** of an open set $U$ of $S$ is that it is of the form $U=V(U) \cap S$ for *some* open set $V(U)$ of the large space $T$. So the proof just applies the definition. There is no claim of non-emptyness per se, but if $U=\emptyset$ this intersection must be empty, of course. Having $\emptyset$ in a cover doesn't really do anything (it adds nothing to the union, we could as well leave it out), but doesn't do harm either.

Because we start with a cover of $S$ in the subspace topology, we have that the union of the $U$'s is $S$ precisely (the $U$'s are all subsets of $S$ and each point of $S$ must be covered by some $U$, so two inclusions hold trivially), while the union of the corresponding $V(U)$'s is potentially (and typically) larger than $S$, so a cover of the subset $S$ of open sets of $T$ in the sense you describe.

So in your notatation we have $$S = \bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U  \text{ and } S \subseteq \bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{U}} V(U)$$